# Можно ли в html переходить на другие страницы через меню сайта без перезагрузки?

Tags: html

Можно ли в html переходить на другие страницы через меню сайта без перезагрузки.
Например:

- Меню сайта
- Главная
- Новости
- Загрузки

Чтобы без перезагрузки С главной переходит на новости или на загрузки

Comment: Ответ: можно (Ajax)

Comment: А как с помощью Ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Можно с перезагрузкой только нужной области - читай [`<frame>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/frame)

Можно используя `ajax`

Comment: А с помощью include

Comment: include в php? php серверный язык! 1 запрос (перезагрузка) - одна страница. Только так

Answer (score 1):

frame ни при чем, перегружать можно любые части.

Автору вопроса советую взглянуть на http://api.jquery.com/load/